# Understanding profiling and memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

Using `Profile` in `Xcode`, with `Leaks tool`, i am looking for leaks in my code .
I than open `call Tree`, and check the functions that i see in there .

`Xcode` will take you to the code and color the lines. sometimes its colored with red , which is a leak of course, but sometimes, it is colored in light brown, and there is a number near the line that say : `20.5%` .

I am trying to understand what this number say , and what the color means ?

I am getting this brown line on this line of code :

```
textL=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(A+B+C,A,view.frame.size.width-A-B-C-A, B)];
```

This is obviously not a leak , but , this line of code us a part of a for loop and is created more than 100 times, to be added to cells in scrollview . Is there something i also have to change here ?

EDIT:

I have this class that is subclass of UIView ,this class has a strong references to labels and imageViews(@properties) . later on i am creating many instances of this class as views that added to scrollvoiew, and save them to array.  could this be the problem? that i have a strong references in that class ?

thanks.

Comment: you can find documentation here, Maybe it will help 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that  that line allocating the `UILabel` was "obviously not a leak." It might not be the source of the leak, but it is the allocation of an object that was later leaked.

When Instruments is informing you of a leak, it's not informing you of the offending line(s) of code that caused the leak (because it has no way of knowing), but rather merely showing you where the leaked object was original allocated.

So, the fact that it's highlighting this line of code would suggest that this item is being leaked (e.g. possibly the view controller that had this line of code is leaking as a result of a strong reference cycle, resulting in any objects for which it maintains strong references, such as this label, to also leak). The fact that there are other objects involved in the leak is further evidenced by the fact that this `UILabel` only accounts for 20.5% of the leak.

Comment: thanks, can you check my edit and see if you can help me understand what could it be ?

Comment: @Curnelious Unfortunately, there's not enough here to diagnose the issue, but I'd suggest you first focus on your `UIView` subclass. Is that getting deallocated properly? Until you confirm that, there's no point in worrying about whether its properties are getting deallocated correctly. I'd wager that this `UIView` subclass (or, even more likely, its view controller) is not getting deallocated properly (probably due to some retain cycle). Start from the top-down.

Comment: @Curnelious I might suggest watching WWDC 2013 video, [Fixing Memory Issues](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/index.php?id=410), for greater insights on tracking down memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

Red lines show where is memory leaking the most, brown line show's memory leak but not so big. The percentage is showing how much memory is leaking in that method (present of all memory leak)

When you run Leaks test, you will see something like this -

[image: Memory leak result]
When you select Leaks, you will see all your leaks over time like (Those read line)
- You can show "Extended details" view at the right side. It will show call tree for the selected memory leak.
In my example it points that I'm leaking in "[CardGameViewController viewDidLoad]"

In the Call Tree view the percentage is showing how much present of all memory was leaked it that method. You can leak memory in many places in the call tree. It helps you to find place with the biggest memory leak and fix it first.
This percentage is really useful for performance optimisation.

[image: Memory leak]